How to import python functions from a module in a local Ansible collection?
I have a local Ansible collection. This is what my folder structure looks like:
/
|_ collections
|  |_ ansible_collections
|     |_ my # Namespace
|        |_ tools # Collection
|           |_ plugins
|              |_ modules
|                 |_ my_module.py # Module
|_ my_playbook.yml

In my_playbook.yml I call the module with <namespace>.<collection>.<module>, e.g.: my.tools.my_module.
This is working fine, but I want to define reusable classes/functions to reference from my_module.py. Where would I put these other libraries?
I tried including them in (for example) plugins/modules/my_lib.py, I tried in plugins/module_utils/my_lib.py, etc. In my_module.py, I've tried importing a bunch of ways:
from my.tools.module_utils.my_lib import my_func
from module_utils.my_lib import my_func
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../module_utils'))
from my_lib import my_func

What's the right way to accomplish this?

module_utils seems to be the correct approach ...

So in my_module.py how would I import the module_utils file? Everything I've tried keeps saying "No module named my_lib", etc.

I haven't an step-by-step answer or prototype available yet, because I would need to check and test by myself before ... But, in order to do so, first I would check how other modules are doing it by reviewing ansible/module_utils source code. Than, double check with the developer guide Using and developing module utilities.

You'd do it like you do any other Python import: from ansible_collections .my.tools.module_utils.my_lib import my_func. Example: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/blob/main/plugins/modules/docker_compose_v2.py#L421

Awesome this worked: from ansible_collections.my.tools.plugins.module_utils.my_lib import my_func thanks!

In general: to debug your python imports, find a way to run print(sys.path) or print("\n".join(sys.path)). The advised way to add paths to that list is to set your PYTHONPATH environment variable before calling your script. sys.path.append(...) sort of works, but make sure you control what you add there: ../module_utils is relative to the active directory, not "the directory of the current python file"

@U880D IMO making an answer from your comment would be worthy.
